# How can I how to click specific button but not all buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to create a button `Add` and `Remove` but i'm having issues that when I click one button and all the others was clicked as well.

Here is my following code:

```
function MyFruits() {

  const fruitsArray = [
    'banana',
    'banana',
    'orange',
    'orange',
    'strawberry',
    'blackberry',
  ];

  const cartArray : any[] = [];

  let unique = [...new Set(fruitsArray)];
  unique.sort((a, b)  => {
    return a.localeCompare(b);
  })
  
  const [addButton, setAddButton] = useState(true);
  const [removeButton, setRemoveButton] = useState(false);
  const [itemList, setItemList] = useState(fruitsArray)

  const [cart, setCart] = useState<typeof cartArray>([])

  const addClick = (fruit: any, index: any) => {
    setItemList([...itemList]);
    setCart([...cart, fruit]);
    setAddButton(false);
    setRemoveButton(true);
  }

  const removeClick = (fruit: any, index: any) => {
    let removeItem = [...cart];
    removeItem = removeItem.filter((cartItem) => cartItem !== fruit);
    setCart(removeItem);
    setAddButton(true);
    setRemoveButton(false);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <ul>
          {unique.map((fruit, index) => (
          <div>
              <li key={index}>{fruit}</li>
              {itemList.length !== 1 && addButton && (
                <button onClick={() => addClick(fruit, index)}>Add</button>
              )}

              {removeButton && (
                <button onClick={() => removeClick(fruit, index)}>Remove</button>
              )}
          </div>
        ))}
        </ul>
        <div className="cart">
        Cart: {cart.map(cartItem => (
          <p>{cartItem}</p>
        ))}
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyFruits;
```

How can I improve my click function for `Add` and `Remove` ?

Comment: Why you know click all button?

Comment: So I created useState `const [addButton, setAddButton] = useState(true);` and similar useState for remove, when one button was clicked all the button I was mapping will click as well

Comment: You really need to have separate state or a particular state object to manage `addButton` and `removeButton` state for each fruit. Currently, you're using same state to manage it for all the fruits.

Comment: @K.vindi how can I separate it ?

Comment: Move the div within your unique.map to its own separate component .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to track the `addButton` and `removeButton` state changes for each and every fruit you've in your array. So better you create state objects such as `addButtonFruits` and `removeButtonFruits` to track them.

I've created a JavaScript implementation similar to your code and try to use it as a supportive material for your implementation.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const fruitsArray = [
    "banana",
    "banana",
    "orange",
    "orange",
    "strawberry",
    "blackberry",
  ];

  const cartArray = [];

  let unique = [...new Set(fruitsArray)];
  unique.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.localeCompare(b);
  });

  const [addButtonFruits, setAddButtonFruits] = useState({});
  const [removeButtonFruits, setRemoveButtonFruits] = useState({});
  const [itemList, setItemList] = useState(fruitsArray);

  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

  /*
    instead of having this useEffect, you can directly set the default state using useState as follows:

        const [addButtonFruits, setAddButtonFruits] = useState(
            {
                banana: true,
                orange: true,
                strawberry: true,
            });
  */
  useEffect(() => {
    const initialAddButtonFruits = {};
    fruitsArray.forEach((each) => (initialAddButtonFruits[each] = true));
    console.log("initial add-fruit-buttons state: ", initialAddButtonFruits);
    setAddButtonFruits(initialAddButtonFruits);
  }, []); // only executed for initial rendering

  const addClick = (fruit, index) => {
    setItemList([...itemList]);
    setCart([...cart, fruit]);

    const addButtonFruitsTemp = addButtonFruits;
    addButtonFruitsTemp[fruit] = false;

    setAddButtonFruits(addButtonFruitsTemp);

    const removeButtonFruitsTemp = removeButtonFruits;
    removeButtonFruitsTemp[fruit] = true;

    setRemoveButtonFruits(removeButtonFruitsTemp);
  };

  const removeClick = (fruit, index) => {
    let removeItem = [...cart];
    removeItem = removeItem.filter((cartItem) => cartItem !== fruit);
    setCart(removeItem);

    const addButtonFruitsTemp = addButtonFruits;
    addButtonFruitsTemp[fruit] = true;

    setAddButtonFruits(addButtonFruitsTemp);

    const removeButtonFruitsTemp = removeButtonFruits;
    removeButtonFruitsTemp[fruit] = false;

    setRemoveButtonFruits(removeButtonFruitsTemp);
  };

  console.log("addButtonFruits: ", addButtonFruits);
  console.log("removeButtonFruits: ", removeButtonFruits);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <ul>
          {unique.map((fruit, index) => (
            <div>
              <li key={index}>{fruit}</li>
              {itemList.length !== 1 && addButtonFruits[fruit] && (
                <button onClick={() => addClick(fruit, index)}>Add</button>
              )}

              {removeButtonFruits[fruit] && (
                <button onClick={() => removeClick(fruit, index)}>
                  Remove
                </button>
              )}
            </div>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <div className="cart">
          Cart:{" "}
          {cart.map((cartItem) => (
            <p>{cartItem}</p>
          ))}
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Following is the view

[image]

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: I am having this issues `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{}'.ts(7053)` at this line `addButtonFruitsTemp[fruit]` & `removeButtonFruitsTemp[fruit]`

Comment: This happens because you're using typescript. By the way, it can be solved in another way, if you configure `addButtonFruits` and `removeButtonFruits` states as arrays to store relevant boolean value (e.g. - `[true, false, false, false, ...]`), instead of using object to the state.

Comment: thank you for helping me out and I am new to react typescript. I am having issues `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.ts(7053)` with the `useEffect` at line `fruitsArray.forEach((each) => (initialAddButtonFruits[each] = true));`